# Unable to delete all objects in the bucket, bucket will not be deleted AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to delete my S3 bucket created by cloudformation. I've tried with delete with aws cli but no luck.

When I tried to delete with following cli,

```
aws s3 rb s3://admin-static-s3-pipelinebucket-ehj8lw6h3r9s --force
```

got that error *"remove_bucket failed: Unable to delete all objects in the bucket, bucket will not be deleted.*"

And when I tried to delete with following cli,

```
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket admin-s3-stack-pipelinebucket-wttbpzw2ixwj
```

got this error *"An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The specified bucket does not exist"*

And oddly, I've found that my those buckets are belong to no region as screen shot. Please let me know how to delete it, those are really annoying to me.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to delete it using the Amazon S3 management console? The missing Region might be due to a missing permission, or because the bucket actually has been deleted but something is cached. Check again tomorrow.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yap, I've tried to delete with management console, first. But I've tried with `aws cli` but no luck. I need to wait for tomorrow.

Comment: Your bucket has been deleted, and should disappear from the console, soon.  The first error was mostly wrong, the second one is right, and the console is behaving as might be expected when a bucket has actually been deleted but not all of the internal cleanup has finished.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yap, they've gone now.

Comment: I am facing same issue while trying to delete S3 bucket created in IBM Cleversafe Cloud Object Storage( called as Vaults ).  I waited for two days. But no luck.

I tried deleting it from IBM Storage Manager, and it succeeded.